# Create new rows based on missing grouped by values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pivot-table

Given the below dataframe, if rows are grouped by first name and last name, how can I find and create new rows for a group that does not have a row for every type in the types list.

So in the example below, two new rows would be created for Bob Jack that are missing from the original dataframe: one with type 'DA' and another with type 'FA', the value columns can be set to 0.

```py
data = {
    'First Name': ['Alice', 'Alice', 'Alice', 'Alice', 'Bob', 'Bob'],
    'Last Name': ['Johnson', 'Johnson', 'Johnson', 'Johnson', 'Jack', 'Jack'],
    'Type': ['CA', 'DA', 'FA', 'GCA', 'CA', 'GCA'],
    'Value': [25, 30, 35, 40, 50, 37]
}

types = ['CA', 'DA', 'FA', 'GCA']
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Will  there only be a single row for each type and person in your dataframe? For example will there be only one row for "CA" and "Alice" in your dataframe or can there be multiple?

Comment: yes one single row for each type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this is to create a dataframe which is all the combinations of names and types, then left join that to the original dataframe. This will create a df with all combinations, with `NaN` values where there was a missing entry in the original data. That can then be filled with `0`. Note that because the value column gets `NaN` values in it, it is converted to type float. You can convert that back to int if desired using `astype({'Value': int})` in the chain:

```py
out = (df[['First Name', 'Last Name']]
    .drop_duplicates()
    .merge(pd.Series(types, name='Type'), how='cross')
    .merge(df, on=['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Type'], how='left')
    .fillna(0)
    # use this astype if you need `Value` to be an int
    .astype({'Value': int})
)
```

Output (with the `astype` to convert `Value` back to int):

```
  First Name Last Name Type  Value
0      Alice   Johnson   CA     25
1      Alice   Johnson   DA     30
2      Alice   Johnson   FA     35
3      Alice   Johnson  GCA     40
4        Bob      Jack   CA     50
5        Bob      Jack   DA      0
6        Bob      Jack   FA      0
7        Bob      Jack  GCA     37
```

Comment: @cottontail harking back to SQL... good idea about the `astype`, I forget you can specify a dict to it like that.

Answer (score 4):

We can pivot the dataframe to make it wide, which creates the missing types for Bob. Then unpivot the frame to make it back into a long dataframe.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = (
    df.pivot_table(columns=['First Name', 'Last Name'], index='Type', values='Value', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
    .unstack()
    .reset_index(name='Value')
)
```

We can also use `set_index`, `unstack` instead of pivot_table for the same effect.

```py
df = (
    df.set_index(['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Type'])['Value']
    .unstack(fill_value=0)
    .reindex(columns=types, fill_value=0)
    .stack()
    .reset_index(name='Value')
)
```

Comment: You have to use `.reindex(types, fill_value=0).unstack()` instead of just `.unstack`, else this won't work in case one of the types is absent from the column ;)

Comment: @mozway yes, I thought to include initially but decided to go with how the data is given and assumed that one of the people has the full list of types.

Answer (score 4):

Using [`janitor`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/)'s [`complete`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete):

```
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor

out = df.complete({'Type': types}, fill_value=0,
                  by=['First Name', 'Last Name'])
```

Output:

```
  First Name Last Name Type  Value
0      Alice   Johnson   CA     25
1      Alice   Johnson   DA     30
2      Alice   Johnson   FA     35
3      Alice   Johnson  GCA     40
4        Bob      Jack   CA     50
5        Bob      Jack   DA      0
6        Bob      Jack   FA      0
7        Bob      Jack  GCA     37
```

Since `types` is the same across all groups, you can get more performance by avoiding the `by` parameter:

```py
out = df.complete(('First Name', 'Last Name'), {'Type':types}, 
                  fill_value={'Type':0})
```

If the column contains all the types, you can avoid the dictionary and pass the column name instead:

```py
out = df.complete(('First Name', 'Last Name'), 'Type', 
                  fill_value={'Type':0})
```

Comment: You gotta love all the great packages available to python.

Comment: Since `Type` is the same for all groups, you can avoid the `by` to get more performance (as data grows of course). I edited the code to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to loop through all the groups and concatenating rows when any type is missing:

```
df= pd.DataFrame(data)
add = []
for name, group  in df.groupby(['First Name', 'Last Name']):
  if set(group['Type'].unique()) != set(types):
    remaining_types = set(types) - set(group['Type'].unique())
    add.append( pd.DataFrame({
        'First Name': name[0],
        'Last Name': name[1],
        'Type': list(remaining_types),
        'Value': 0,
    }))
pd.concat([df] + add).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
  First Name Last Name Type  Value
0      Alice   Johnson   CA     25
1      Alice   Johnson   DA     30
2      Alice   Johnson   FA     35
3      Alice   Johnson  GCA     40
4        Bob      Jack   CA     50
5        Bob      Jack  GCA     37
6        Bob      Jack   DA      0
7        Bob      Jack   FA      0
```